# Lower bound for the spectralradius of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

Any submultiplicative norm (for example the row-sum-norm) is an upper bound for
 the spectralradius of a matrix A. But is there a way to get a suitable LOWER
 bound for the spectralradius ?

Motivation : I would like to have a lower bound for the eigenvalues of a matrix
              with positive integer entries. In particular, is there a nxn-matrix
              A with positive integer entries and the integer eigenvalues 1..n ?
              The answer for n>1 seems to be no. Even more interesting would be 
              the following : If a nxn-matrix A has positive integer entries
              and distinct positive integer eigenvalues (such as 
              [ [4,1,1] , [1,2,1] , [1,1,2] ])
              what is the least possible value for the largest eigenvalue (in
              the example it is 5 because the eigenvalues are 1,2 and 5).

Comment: An $n\times n$ matrix with positive integer entries and eigenvalues $1,\ldots ,n$ would be $\mbox{diag}(1,\ldots,n)$. You can add any strictly upper triangular matrix with positive integer entries to this and still maintain the eigenvalues.

Comment: The entries should be positive, not only non-negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with strictly positive entries (actually you just need it to be [irreducible](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReducibleMatrix.html)), you can apply the [Perron-Frobenius Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem) which asserts that the eigenvalue $\lambda$ with largest magnitude is positive, simple and the associated eigenvector has strictly positive entries. In particular, with these special settings you may apply the Collatz-Wielandt Theory which tells you that for every $x>0$ (i.e. each component of $x$ is strictly positive) with $\|x\|=1$,
$$\min_{i=1,\ldots,n}\frac{(Ax)_{i}}{x_i} \leq \lambda \leq \max_{i=1,\ldots,n}\frac{(Ax)_{i}}{x_i} $$
This is a powerful lower/upper bound generator for the largest eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ (obviously equality holds if and only if $Ax = \lambda x$).

Comment: So, there is indeed no nxn-matrix A (n>1) with positive integer entries and the eigenvalues 1,2,...,n. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just noticed that I was too fast with my conclusion, nevertheless your answer is very helpful!